# How to make horizontal and vertical complex view with UIScrollView swift 4

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, swift4.1.5

I need to design a view which fast have a horizontal UIScrollview and bottom of fast view has some collection view and horizontal list view. check the image.

[image]

Comment: you can do this with add Uiview in side scrollview and make your view hight and width according to your content in storyboard set vertical and horizontal scroll enbled

Comment: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/bsyellowpages-e5bc014f-ce86-4231-9f6d-1b52d32f2608 use this library for card swap scroll .

Comment: Thanks for your comment But this is only for upper horizontal slider that i make using UIScrollView. if i added more view bellow  slider than upper horizontal slider not working